# How to convert a list to a vector of values of one of its fields?

Tags: r, list, field

```
l = list()
l[[1]] = list(); l[[1]]$asdf = 'jkl'; l[[1]]$qwerty = 5
l[[2]] = list(); l[[2]]$asdf = 'zxcv'; l[[2]]$qwerty = 55
l[[3]] = list(); l[[3]]$asdf = 'poiu'; l[[3]]$qwerty = 555
```

Now I want to somehow extract the `qwerty`s from this list; ie I want to obtain an equivalent of `c(5, 55, 555)` since the values of the `qwerty` fields of consecutive elements of this list are `5`, `55`, `555`.

How to obtain this?

(In case I've fallen into XY: what I *really* want to achieve is to get the element of this list whose `qwerty` field has greatest value; and I thought one way to obtain this was to extract the `qwerty`s to an intermediate `numeric` I could then call `max` on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `pluck` the "qwerty" elements by looping through the `list` with `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dbl(l, pluck, "qwerty")
#[1]   5  55 555
```

---

Or using `sapply` from `base R`

```
sapply(l, `[[`, "qwerty")
#[1]   5  55 555
```

wrap with `max` to get the max value

```
max(sapply(l, `[[`, "qwerty"))
#[1] 555
```

If it is the element of the `list`

```
i1 <- which.max(sapply(l, `[[`, "qwerty"))
l[i1]
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$asdf
#[1] "poiu"

#[[1]]$qwerty
#[1] 555
```

---

Or another option is

```
l %>%
    transpose %>%
    .$qwerty %>% 
    unlist %>% 
    which.max %>% 
    magrittr::extract(l, .)
```